# Android view elements appear black (only on OnePlus 6 with Android Pie)

Tags: android, android-view, android-9.0-pie

I'm working on an `MVVM Android application`. When I run the app on an `OnePlus 6` with `Android Pie` all views appear in a sort of "**dark theme**". All the `CardViews`, `Spinners` and `Dialogs` through the app have a black background out of nowhere.

I made a new app with a `CardView` and let it run on the `OnePlus6`. That app was normal with a white `CardView` background.

I also tried to build the app on lots of different phones but only on the `OnePlus 6` this sudden "**dark** **theme**" appears. 
The `OnePlus 6` uses the light theme, so that can not be the problem.

Does anyone know where this comes from? What code can I upload to make things extra clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the develop options on the phone. I tried to turn that off and on and for a while it worked in the normal way.

I don't know why it turns to black but it has to do with the Developer Options.

Answer (score 0):

one plus 6 has his own theme engine so you have first to installs themes to the mobile using for example : "substratum" then it will be better.

Comment: But I can't let all my users install an app before they can use this app? So I need an other solution.